# Parameters or keys in $attachments['#attached']['html_head'][] in page_attachments

Tags: 8

While debugging extra markup in head section I came across one attachment in adsense module.
It is

```
  $attachments['#attached']['html_head'][] = [
    [
      '#tag' => '',
      '#theme' => 'adsense_comment',
      '#comment' => 'adsense page-level ads: ads disabled',
    ],
    'adsense_ads_disabled',
];
```

What is this second parameter or key `adsense_ads_disabled` called? And what is it's role in modifying the template.

Comment: I tried searching in the project directory but there is only one occurrence of `adsense_ads_disabled`.

Comment: I believe it is a key that can be used if/when altering the output of the head.

Comment: Yeah, it is a unique identifier for that kind of attachment, to avoid adding things twice and also being able to identify it. it's an extremely weird API.

Comment: Agree it's just an identifier to hook and alter this attachment.